# Make date from string

Tags: php

I have some string like this.

```
$str = '14032017';
```

I want convert it to date format and show the result as **14-03-2017**

I already try this but still didn't work :

```
<?php

$str = '14032017';
$strdate = strtotime($str);
$date = date('d-m-Y',$strdate);

echo $date;

?>
```

How could I to do that ?

Comment: Is this `$str` your unix timestamp?

Comment: I just get that string and I want convert it. @SahilGulati

Comment: It seems that it's not a timestamp.. @SahilGulati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = '14032017';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $str);
if($date === false){
   echo 'Invalid Date';
}else{
   echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DateTime Class for this.
( i assume that your str is in dmY format )

```
    $str = '14032017';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $str);
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); // Will print 14/03/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str = '14032017';

    $strdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY',$str)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Use the correct format in your string.
for 14032017 = dmY
for 14-03-2017 = d-m-Y etc ...